# Influence power checks and multiple affected

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars-age-of-rebellion, star-wars-force-and-destiny

For Influence, the **basic power** only affects 1 target, and one needs the Magnitude upgrade to influence multiple targets with one go.

The Control upgrade increases your successes/advantages for a specific social roll. Is that also limited to the same number of targets affected by the base power? Or is it so that EVERYONE is affected who can hear the force user?

Answer (score 2):

### Influence and Multiple Targets

The system is built around a minimum of rolls. When upgrading from a single target of *Influence* to multiple targets, those affected are all affected by one roll of the dice pool. You do not need to roll for *Influence* for each target affected.

When resisting the effects of *Influence* and other powers, there are times when it is appropriate to have an opposed roll of *Discipline* vs *Discipline* or a similar pool. This likewise does not need to be a series of rolls for each affected character. *Minions* can be represented as a *Minion group*, and *Rivals* can be represented via choosing a primary target (the person in charge, as we see in the films) and allow the narrative to cover the others falling in line.

You may want to roll separately if there is more than one *Nemesis*-level character affected, but again it is not necessary.

### Magnitude Upgrade Note

It should be noted that the *Magnitude* upgrade for *Influence* can be invoked multiple times, so even if the character has it only once, they can still affect multiple targets if they generate enough Force Point resources.

### Control Upgrade and Multiple Targets

The *Control* upgrade allows the Force Sensitive character to add a social roll (Coercion, Negotiation, etc) to the Influence power roll. The force dice and the character's dice pool for the social skill roll are rolled together. This is limited to one target, just like with the base power, unless the character invokes *Magnitude* to add additional targets as well.